# Joomla 2.5 Uncaught ReferenceError: Joomla is not defined

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5, referenceerror

I just upgraded a joomla application from version 1.7 to 2.5... After the application initially worked I installed k2, upon uninstalling I now see a Uncaught ReferenceError: Joomla is not defined in my console.

it prevents the article editor from loading.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Joomla is not defined
```

it happens in this block of code I believe...

```
submitbutton = function(task) {
    if (task == 'article.cancel' || document.formvalidator.isValid(document.id('item-form'))) {
        if (tinyMCE.get("jform_articletext").isHidden()) {
            tinyMCE.get("jform_articletext").show()}; 
            tinyMCE.get("jform_articletext").save();
            Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById('item-form'));
        } else {
            alert('Invalid form');
        }
    }
}
```

I won't even bother to beat around the bush... I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

check your pluggin loading order and make sure all javascript needed is loaded before k2 this might help...

Answer (score 0):

I was getting exactly the same thing, it turned out it was down to JCE Editor. I updated it to the latest version and this fixed this bug for me